# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'product'

Tags: python, html, django

Hi I'm building a Webshop. Now I'm trying to add and delete their quantity and calculate the total price of them but I don't know how I could get the product.name or the product.quantity without getting an error as shown below.

this is my views.py :

```
def add_cart(request):
    memid = request.session.get( "memid" )
    pnum = request.GET.get("pnum")
    product = Product.objects.get(pnum=pnum)
    try:
        cart = Order.objects.get(order_id_id = memid, prod_num_id = pnum)
        if cart:
            if cart.product.pname == product.pname:
                cart.quantity += 1
                cart.save()
    except Order.DoesNotExist:
        user = Sign.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
        cart = Order(
            user=user,
            product=product,
            quantity=1,
        )
        cart.save()
    return redirect('cart')

def minus_cart_item(request):
    pnum = request.GET.get("pnum")
    cart_item = Order.objects.get(prod_num_id = pnum)
    product = Product.objects.get(pnum=pnum)
    try:
        for item in cart_item:
            if item.product.pname == product.pname:
                if item.quantity > 1:
                    item.quantity -= 1
                    item.save()
                return redirect('cart')
            else:
                return redirect('cart')
    except Order.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
```

Now I'm trying to get pnum and quan from Query set but the error describes that

```
AttributeError at /order/add_cart
'Order' object has no attribute 'product'
```

models.py

```
class Order( models.Model) :
    onum = models.AutoField(null=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    prod_num = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(Sign, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quan = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100)])
```

this my html :

```
{% for i in j %}
<tr>
<td>{{i.prod_num.pnum}}</td>
<td><img src={{i.prod_num.image.url}} width="100" height="100"></td>
<td>{{i.prod_num.pname}}</td>
<td>{{i.prod_num.price}}원</td>
<td>{{i.quan}}
<input type="text" name="amount" value="1" size="3" onchange="change();">
<input type="button" value=" + " onclick="location='add_cart?pnum={{i.prod_num.pnum}}&memid={{memid}}'">
<input type="button" value=" - " onclick="location='minus_cart_item?pnum={{i.prod_num.pnum}}&memid={{memid}}'">
<td>{{i.prod_num.price}}원</td>
<td><button type="submit" onclick="location='del_cart?onum={{i.onum}}'">삭제</button></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: In your `Order` model, you call the associated product `prod_num`, so I guess you need to call `item.prod_num` instead of `item.product`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've already tried item.prod_num but it doesn't work. Now I have other error `Order matching query does not exist.`. How can I solve it?

Comment: What errror do you get?

Comment: I got NoReverseMatch error coming. I created another views named `add_cart_pro` and made a redirect from `add_cart`.